# HTTP status 404 when running project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, jsp, tomcat

I have created a Dynamic web project in eclipse. I am trying to run my index.jsp at http://localhost:8080/MyProject/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp but get the HTTP status 404. Why do I get HTTP status 404? What can I do to fix it?

I have done the following:

- Made sure that my Tomcat apache server is working. (I can go to the
  default apache site when starting the server)
- Added MyProject to the server.
- Added The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" to the classpath.
- Made sure that the server is running on port number 8080.
- Index.jsp is the default created by eclipse.

Please let me know if you need more information in order to figure it out.

Comment: try instead: http://localhost:8080/MyProject/index.jsp

Comment: placing JSP outside of the WEB-INF folder is not good way so we have to call JSP file by code only other than welcome file list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default WEB-INF directory is not accessible directly due to security reasons. That is the way it is intended to work. Try placing your JSP outside the WEB-INF directory. That should work.

Comment: This was it. Techically you were all right but you also explained why.

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:8080/MyProject/jsp/index.jsp 
use this link page will open

or right click on the page and run on server it will automatically open the page